# A class extending Ext.Window ignores constructor parameters

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I am trying to create a popup window by extending Ext.Window class:

```
Ext.define('mine.nameCreationPopup',{
extend: 'Ext.Window',
alias: 'nameCreationPopup',

config:{
    title: 'aTitle', //default value
    width: 700 //default value
},

constructor: function(config){
    this.initConfig(config);
    this.superclass.constructor.call
    (this, {
        title: config.title,
        width: config.width,
        height: 300, //ignored from now on
        layout: 'fit',
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px;',
        modal: true,
        resizable: false
    });
}
```

Now, creation:

```
var pops = Ext.create('nameCreationPopup',{title:'Dunno'});
pops.show();
pops.center();
```

Width and title are currectly set (title is Dunno, while width is 700 as default value) anyway height and the rest of window attributes are just ignored.
How come?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way how Ext.define should look like. Either configure the window directly (inline) or use `initComponent`. Inline configuration:

```
Ext.define('mine.nameCreationPopup',{
    extend: 'Ext.Window',
    alias: 'widget.nameCreationPopup',
    title: 'aTitle',
    width: 700,
    height: 300, //ignored from now on
    layout: 'fit',
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px;',
    modal: true,
    resizable: false
});
```

initComponent:

```
Ext.define('mine.nameCreationPopup',{
    extend: 'Ext.Window',
    alias: 'widget.nameCreationPopup',
    initComponent:function() {
        Ext.applyIf(this, {
            title: 'aTitle',
            width: 700,
            height: 300, //ignored from now on
            layout: 'fit',
            bodyStyle: 'padding:5px;',
            modal: true,
            resizable: false
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    } 
});
```